# What is the Sever IP Address

Tags: python, django

Hi sir i have hosted my python application on pythonanywhere and i am using external api which required ip whitelisting for payment processing ,
I would like to know the sever ip and is it static or dynamic

I am unable to locate the sever ip from my dashboard.

Comment: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticIPForExternalAllowlists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonanywhere: getting the IP address for database access whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686528/pythonanywhere-getting-the-ip-address-for-database-access-whitelist)

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to your server console open a "Bash" console and type this:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

this will display the server's public IP address.
this is the current IP address and it might change if the server is restarted or reconfigured.